# How to pass multiple objects between destination fragments when using Navigation Component and data binding?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-databinding, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

I successfully managed to pass an object from a fragment to another when using data binding. This is my layout file:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data class="ItemDataBinding">
        <variable
            name="item"
            type="com.example.myapp.Item" />
    </data>

    //Views of ItemsFragment
</layout>
```

And this is my code:

```
action = actionItemsFragmentToItemFragment();
action.setItem(clickedItem);
Navigation.findNavController(rootView).navigate(action);
```

As you can see, I can call `setItem()` method as it is defined in my layout file. However, if I add another variable in the same layout file:

```
<variable
    name="shop"
    type=type="com.example.myapp.Shop"/>
```

And rebuild the project, there is **no** `setShop()` method available so I can pass another object to the next fragment. How can I solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a confusion between the variables defined in the layout and for the actual navigation. If I understood you correctly, you would like to send two variables between navigation destinations using an action. Which variables are available as action parameters is defined in your navigation graph, so you need to ensure that in your navigation graph xml something similar to this is included:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/itemFragment"
...>
    <argument
        android:name="item"
        app:argType="integer" />
    <argument
        android:name="shop"
        app:argType="string" />
</fragment>
```

As a result, you will have the parameters available to each action that navigate to the `ItemFragment`:

```
action = actionItemsFragmentToItemFragment(1,"string")
```

You can access the parameters in the ItemFragment using `getArguments()`. Find more details in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#Safe-args).
In the next step, you can use these variables to set them for use in databinding.